# Android: this.getApplication() returns NULL pointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm running the following line in an Activity, which is within the same application, but in a different package:

```
AppObject appObj = (AppObject)this.getApplication();
// FYI: AppObject is my extension class of Application.
```

It returns only a null pointer, while when I move it to the "main" package and run it from there it returns the application reference as expected.

I've defined the activity in my AndroidManifest.xml  with the full qualified class name, since it is in another package: `<activity android:name="com.foo.bar.TestActivity"></activity>`

---

**Update:** As suggested in a question below `android:name="AppObject"` was already in the `<application>` tag of the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 31):

It's important to call `getApplication()` in the activity's `onCreate()` method, not in the constructor.

Comment: Very important point, not mentioned in the documentation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: interestingly, this calling getApplication before onCreate seemed to work for a colleague just fine on a samsung galaxy note 3, but on my nexus 5 i saw a crash.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I was already in a desperate state because I had NullPointerExceptions at every way I tried to get on SharedPreferences. This solved it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need the update application tag to AndroidManifest.xml with your class name, which is extended from Application, with proper package name.

```
<application android:name=".AppObject">
```

As per **Application** tag google docs, *Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.*

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my question. But I've had that already in my Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Just run into the same thing, having refactored all my code still got the same issue, noticed that I was setting the local `mApplication` variable in the constructor, it should go in the `onCreate()`, I think all the objects in the manifest may be constructed first before `getApplication()` is setup so you need to call `getApplication()` in or after `onCreate()` has been called.  Haven't refactored all my code back again to see if this works for different packages (sigh).

Answer (score -2):

I think, it isn't a `null` pointer, but your function  which you want to use next in the class `AppObject` maybe wrong.

Comment: Please, explain. Why do you think so?

Comment: I have meet your mistake once, when I check code and find this reason,I'm new to this field and hope this will be helpful to you.